# Postgresql - pass parameters to COPY in an sql script

Tags: postgresql, psql

I can use the `-v v1=foo` syntax just fine for queries in my sql script, but I can't figure out how to use that parameter in a copy statement. I'd like to execute the script like:

```
psql -d my_db -f ./exports.sql -v v1="'/Users/username/test.json'"
```

And in the script do some version of:

```
copy (
 select * from bar     
) to :v1;
```

or

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE
   'copy (select * from bar) to ' || :v1;
END $$
```

or

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE
   format('copy (select * from bar) to %L',:v1);
END $$
```

But none of the above work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable substitution doesn't work in a string literal.

Use `psql`'s `\gexec`:

```
SELECT format(
          $$copy (select * from bar) to %L$$,
          :v1
       ) \gexec
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That definitely works. Finally I have a way to not hardcode the export paths for copy

Comment: I'm getting stuck again when I try to use %L value concatenated with a string, what's the proper way to do that? As in COPY ... FROM %L||'myfile.csv' ?

Comment: Sounds like a new question.

Comment: It's still passing parameters to copy in a script executed from psql, or am I missing something larger than that?

Comment: Comments are not for follow-up questions. Please ask a new one.

Comment: Ok, I created a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395887/postgresql-pass-dynamic-file-path-to-copy-in-an-sql-script-called-from-psql