# Postgresql - pass dynamic file path to COPY in an sql script called from psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

This is very similar to the question here:

[Postgresql - pass parameters to COPY in an sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181362/postgresql-pass-parameters-to-copy-in-an-sql-script)

But I'm stuck on how to use the format strategy that totally works when copying to a file, but I need to copy from a file, and pass in part of the file path:

```
--this doesnt work
SELECT format(
      $$copy mytable(mycolums) from %L || 'my/file/path.csv'$$,
      :v1
   ) \gexec
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the concatenation into the argument to `format`:

```
SELECT format(
      $$copy mytable(mycolums) from %L$$,
      :v1 || 'my/file/path.csv'
   ) \gexec
```