# \copy command on psql

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

Can anyone help me on the issue i'm encountering when doing psql query via shell script.
here is my code:

```
infile="oos_item_dtl_stat.dat";

psql -tAqc "\COPY DP.OOS_ITEM_DETAIL_STAT
(
  SCAN_DT \"TO_DATE(:SCAN_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy')\"
, SCAN_TM \"TO_DATE(:SCAN_TM, 'HH24:MI:SS ')\"
, SCAN_NBR
, SCANNED_NBR_TYP_CD
, UPC_ID
, PROMO_IND_CD
, EXPRESS_PROC_IND
, SCAN_TYP_CD
, USER_INITIAL_ID
, RLSE_DTE \"TO_DATE(:RLSE_DTE, 'mm/dd/yyyy')\"
, RLSE_TM \"TO_DATE(:RLSE_TM, 'HH24:MI:SS'\"
)
FROM $infile WITH (DELIMITER '|', NULL ' ');";
```

Here is my error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""TO_DATE(:SCAN_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy')""
LINE 1: COPY  ( select SCAN_DT TO_DATE ( :SCAN_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) , ...
```

The infile value is:

```
09/21/2020|10:58:34|88570294      | |0| | |O|   |09/21/2020|11.06.31

09/21/2020|10:58:34|88630062      | |0| | |O|   |09/21/2020|11.06.31

09/21/2020|10:58:34|001853724148  |U|1853724148|N|Y|O|   |09/21/2020|11.06.31
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the initial `\` of the PSQL command?

Comment: that is to enclosed the whole psql query inside my shell script.

Comment: I don't see why POSIX shell would enjoy a backslash here. It's inside double quotes and therefore does not even have any special meaning to the shell.  You just pass the backslash to SQL. What error do you get when you erase it?

Comment: without the backslash it referring to a server side copy of psql and so I must use \copy for it to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql - pass parameters to COPY in an sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181362/postgresql-pass-parameters-to-copy-in-an-sql-script)

Comment: Great observation. I did not even notice that the OP was interpolating something in this string! @Raizen: You need to amend your post by showing the content of `infile`  (i.e. `printf '%s\n' "$infile"`.

Comment: You can copy a query to a file.  Copying a query from a file makes no sense.